# c# HtmlAgilityPack HTML parsing issue

Tags: html-parsing

I have this html

```
<div class="postrow firs">
        <h2 class="title icon">
            This is the title
        </h2>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="post_message_1668079">
                <blockquote class="postcontent restore ">
                <div>Category</div>
                                         <div>Authour: Kim</div>
                    line 1<br /> line2
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      <div class="postrow">
        <h2 class="title icon">
            This is the title
        </h2>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="post_message_1668079">
                <blockquote class="postcontent restore ">
                <div>Category</div>
                    line 1<br /> line2
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to extract the following things from each div having class "postrow" and may also have another classes like `<div class="postrow first">`. So the class "first" is not my concern, just need to have "postrow" in the beginning.

1. The content inside the  tag with class title
2. the HTML from the "blockquote" tag. But not any div withing this
   tag.

Code I tried:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml("http://localhost/vanilla/");
            List<string> facts = new List<string>();
            foreach (HtmlNode li in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='postrow']"))
            {
                facts.Add(li.InnerHtml);
                foreach (String s in facts)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += s + "/n";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has issue you have to give html as string not the path

```
doc.LoadHtml("http://localhost/vanilla/");
```

instead

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/vanilla/");
String response = request.GetResponse();

doc.loadHtml(response);
```

now iterate the parsed html